# Is it customary for a moderator to delete comments that aren't offensive or off topic due to an edit?

Tags: discussion

It's been a while since I've been super active on SF, so apologies if things have changed in the last couple of years.

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/847952/10472) originally referenced an incorrect piece of information posted by a moderator. What you can't see is that I left a comment saying that one piece of the answer was incorrect. Since then, the question was edited and my comment was removed.

Is this typical practice from a moderation perspective?

Comment: "When should moderators delete comments?

Same advice as for flaggers: when they offer nothing of value to either the author of the post or to future readers." [A guide to moderating comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237982/213575)

Answer (score 7):

Did the edit correct the answer? Hopefully it did.

I can't speak to whether or not this is "typical", but IMHO I'd rather the author acknowledge and thank commenters for noting the incorrect information and calling it out instead of just deleting the comment, thereby taking (implicit) credit for the correction.

I'll leave it up to the moderator who deleted it to speak specifically on their motivations.

Comment: It did. It was something to the effect of *"I've never heard of limiting the use of the term Domain Controller to just the PDC Emulator. That part is incorrect"*

Comment: @MDMarra I've undeleted the comment. I think it should stay...

Answer (score 3):

> I left a comment saying that one piece of the answer was incorrect.

In addition to voting down that is exactly how the site is supposed to work, with people contributing and the community and experts with even better insights ensuring that the better answers arise to the top and that junk doesn't.

Thank you for that.

> Since then, the question was edited and my comment was removed.

I could only agree with your assessment. (and voted up on the comment, but that doesn't really gain you any internet points)

And although in hindsight I can only agree with [EEAA's advise](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/9107/37681) also one of the standard flags for comments is *"obsolete"* for when they no longer make sense with regards to the current state of a question or answer.  I (still) think such is the case here. My edit shows agreement and the comment has become redundant.

Comment: I'd agree with you that if all we care about are the rules, then sure the comment should be deleted. I guess my in my answer, I was trying to express a more nuanced, personal view, that if a comment helps the answer-er to clarify things, then one should consider thanking that person for their correction.